# Vuex state не обновляется при обновлении страницы (старые значения в state)

Tags: localstorage, vuex

```
export const state = {
all: [{
    title: 'игрушка 1',
    item: '123',
},
{
    title: 'игрушка 2',
    item: '456',
},
{
    title: 'игрушка 3',
    item: '789',
}],
```

}
}

изменил Item вручную, а при отправке данных старые значения ( которые были до изменений).
Обновление страницы не помогает. Помогает только очистка LocalStorage вручную.
Как сделать что бы данные обновлялись при перезагрузки страницы ?

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from "vuex"
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'

import modules from './modules'


Vue.use(Vuex)

 const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({     storage: window.localStorage
 })

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules,
     plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin]
})

for (const moduleName of Object.keys(modules)) {
    if (modules[moduleName].actions.init) {
        store.dispatch(`${moduleName}/init`)
    }
}

export default store
```

При отключении VuexPersistence  работать начинает нормально , наверно я его как то не так подключил

Comment: Vuex не хранит данные в LocalStorage, скорее всего это спецификация вашего проекта. Уточните куда вы отправляете данные, случайно не в LocalStorage?

Comment: я нашел в чем причина, был подключен vuex-persist. возможно я его не правильно подключил